# Issue with onClick method

Tags: java, android, xml

I wrote a **xml** code in **android** **studio** to udate the views when button click happens but I am getting **error**. please help.

XML code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/next_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="submit"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="order"/>
```

Java Code:

```
      public void order(View view) {
            int quantity = 2;
            display(quantity);
            displayPrice(quantity *  5);
        }
```

log cat:

> 08-02 11:58:00.775 25553-25553/com.example.android.justjava E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 ****Process: com.example.android.justjava, PID: 25553
>                                                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method order(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'next_button'****
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5233)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21209)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: where did you put order function.

Comment: please post all your activity code

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `android:onClick="order"` from xml and also remove the `order` method from activity.

Put this code in your OnCreate Method of Activity.

```
Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
               int quantity = 2;
               display(quantity);
               displayPrice(quantity *  5);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have feeling its simple issue , make sure you call `public void order(View view)`where you inflate your layout using `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

**main.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" > 
    <!-- your button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="submit"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="order"/>
     <!--other view goes here ..... -->

    </LinearLayout>
```

**java code**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void order(View v){
// make toast only to testing , then add your method later 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

use this sample for button control:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button b1;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
  b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"YOUR MESSAGE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
  });
 }
}
```